# AppleScripting an MSWord find operation

Tags: ms-word, applescript

I'm trying to convert a Word VBA procedure to an AppleScript and only having partial luck.

Here's the first version of the VBA procedure:

```
Public Sub postprocessMerges1() 
    Dim rng As Range 

    Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory 

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False

        Do
            .Text = "..."
            .Execute 
            If .Found Then
                .Parent.Select 
                Set rng = Selection.Range
                rng.MoveStart unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=-1
                rng.MoveEndUntil cset:=Chr(13)
                rng.Text = formatAmounts(rng.Text)
            End If 
        Loop While .Found
    End With 
End Sub
```

And here's my corresponding AppleScript:

```
on postprocessMerges()
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        home key selection move unit a story extend by moving
        set selFind to find object of selection
        clear formatting selFind
        set foundIt to true
        repeat while foundIt
            set foundIt to execute find selFind find text "..." wrap find stop with match forward without find format
            if foundIt then
                set foundRng to text object of selection
                set foundRng to move start of range foundRng by a paragraph item count -1
                set foundRng to move range end until foundRng characters {return}
                set tt to (content of foundRng)
                set (content of foundRng) to my formatAmounts(tt)
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end postprocessMerges
```

Okay, so that works just fine. However, I'd like it to be better. The way the script is currently written, it actually jumps from hit to hit, highlighting the found text and performing the replacement generated by the formatAmounts subroutine. Not bad, but when you're working with a 200+ page document, it gets a little tedious to see that happening onscreen.

So in VBA, I can do this:

```
Public Sub postprocessMerges2()

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False

        Do
            .Text = "..."
            .Execute
            If .Found Then
                With .Parent
                    .MoveStart unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=-1
                    .MoveEndUntil cset:=Chr(13)
                    .Text = formatAmounts(.Text)
                    .Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                End With
            End If
        Loop While .Found
    End With
End Sub
```

This will perform the exact same action as the first procedure, but it does so on the document's content range rather than the selection range and so I don't have to watch Word jump around from page to page to page. Much more preferable, but not something I've been able to emulate in AS.

Specifically, I can't seem to get the hit range each time through the loop without selecting it first. The find object in Word's AS dictionary doesn't have a Parent property I can access like I do in VBA.

Is there anything I'm missing? Is what I do in the second VBA proc actually replicable in AS?

This is using Word 2011 and AppleScript 2.3 on OS X 10.9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably be a comment, but...

> Is what I do in the second VBA proc actually replicable in AS?

Let me put it this way. I think you will probably end up using the Selection object a lot more in AS than you are probably used to doing in VBA. In this case, in VBA, the Find.Execute should return a new Range, but in AS it just returns true/false. If you look it up in the AS dictionary, it looks as if the execute find should return a "text range/insertion point" but what it actually returns is what is stated in the description at the top of the entry for "execute find", i.e. a boolean. The find object does not have a range. So it is difficult to see how to get the range of the thing you just found. As far as I can tell, using execute find in AS with a find object derived from a range object is only useful in the situation where you can specify the replacment object and do the entire replace in the execute.

It might also be useful to read Matt Neuberg's comments in [this conversation](http://www.textndata.com/forums/word-applescript-reference-121585.html)

Comment: Well, I guess that's pretty much what I expected but hoped wasn't the case. And I had noticed the contradiction in the AS dictionary as to what execute find returns. Shame that the Office Mac team hasn't done a better job at making Word (and Excel) scriptable; AppleScript is painful enough, but not even nearly 20 years of AS experience (though most of it not all that complex) prepared me for trying to script Word.