MS word applescript find and select text in app (not find and replace)
I want to make a auto-cue / text follow in MS word with applescript.
So i want the document to fysically go the the text what automatically is going in to the applescript.
here is the script i'm working with now:
tell application "Microsoft Word"
            activate
            if not (exists active document) then
                display dialog "Er is geen actief document."
                return
            end if
            set myFind to find object of text object of active document
            set properties of myFind to {match case:false, match whole word:false, match wildcards:false, forward:true}
            
            set content of myFind to prefix & CueText & posix
            display dialog content of myFind as string
            set foundRange to execute find myFind
            if foundRange is not equal to missing value then
                select object of foundRange as string
            else
                display dialog "Tekst niet gevonden."
            end if
        end tell

but:
find myFind
returns "true" and not the position of the text i'm searching for
Also "select" doesn't work because of this but could not really find explanation in the documentation:
select object of foundRange
returns error "object of true kan niet worden opgevraagd. " number -1728 from object of true
(translation: The object of true cannot be retrieved.)
select object of foundRange as string
returns: error "object of true kan niet in type string worden omgezet." number -1700 from object of true to string'
(translation: The object of true cannot be converted to type string.)
but thats logical because its a true/false state.
I'm only not sure how to solve to get the position of the found text....

This is nearly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746273/applescripting-an-msword-find-operation . The upshot is that unlike in VBA, when you Find using a range, the range doesn't change to be the found range. So you really have to use the find object of the selection instead.

According to Word Applescript dictionnary, the command "exectue find" only sends back true/false if target is found or not. It does not send back the location of the found text. Even if you try to replace only the first occurance (ie replace replace replace one), Word does not change the cursor location. therefore, you can't know, with that method, where is your target. Is it not better to look for VBA instead ?

@jonsson this is exactly what I was looking for! weird that i didn't find it my self, sorry about that.
i have it mostly working, i now only need to figure out it only searches from the selection marker to the end of the document instead of the whole document to keep the order right. but i will figure that out!
i'll post the results when finished

the final script is actually pretty simple:
tell application id "com.figure53.QLab.5" to tell front workspace
  set CueText to q number of last item of (selected as list) -- q name and q number are interchangeable

  set prefix to "L" -- if your script has que numbers with a prefix letter or symbol but your qlab cuenumbers don't you can manually add it here

  set match_case_sensitive to false -- case sensitive finds can be be usefull if cuenumbers in the script always have the same prefix
  set match_whole_word to true -- set to true makes it that if you look for "L2" you won't find "L24")
  set match_wildcards to false
  set find_format to true


  if CueText is "" then
    display dialog "Cue find text is empty"
  else
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        set selFind to find object of selection
        clear formatting selFind
        set properties of selFind to {match case:match_case_sensitive, match whole word:match_whole_word, match wildcards:match_wildcards, format:find_format}
        set foundIt to execute find selFind find text prefix & CueText wrap find stop
    end tell
  end if 
end tell

So every time this script is triggerd it finds the text in the cue number from qlab.
If there are multiple same finds it wil always find the next one from the selection marker in word.
